# Cannot communicate between ROS 2 (in Docker container) on Raspberry Pi and ROS 2 on Laptop

Tags: ros2, network, docker

My setup is:

- ROS 2 Galactic on my laptop (Ubuntu 20.04)
- ROS 2 Humble in a Docker container on a Raspberry Pi 4 (Ubuntu Server 22.04)

Testing communication using:

- *ros2 multicast send* and *ros2 multicast receive* I get no results.
- *ros2 topic pub /chatter std_msgs/msg/String "data: Hello world"* and *ros2 topic list* gives no results
- docker run --net=host makes no difference
- ROS_DOMAIN_ID are both the same

How can I diagnose this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've established that the `ros2 multicast` tools do not return results, you should look at your router to ensure it supports multicast. You could also see if running the ROS natively on the Raspberry Pi encounters the same issues.

If you cannot make changes to the router, you may be able to get the nodes to communicate through a discovery server: https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Advanced/Discovery-Server/Discovery-Server.html

Also, if either machine is running a firewall, you'll need to configure that to allow ROS traffic to pass.

Here is a similar question (WSL to Raspberry Pi): [FastDDS: demo_nodes_cpp between WSL2 and Raspberry Pi](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/105511/fastdds-demo-nodes-cpp-between-wsl2-and-raspberry-pi/105557#105557)